# Android Emulator + Ionic App + websocket not working

Tags: android, ionic-framework, websocket, parse-platform

I have an ionic app which uses websockets it works no problem on iOS but on Android in the Android Studio Emulator it doesnt seem to be able to pick up any of the websocket connections.

Does anybody know if Android or its Emulator has some specific issue with Websockets ? especially in the context of an ionic webview app

I am using parse platforms JS SDK and basically followed this tutorial https://www.back4app.com/docs/platform/parse-server-live-query-example but nothing triggers in android for any subscription hooks

```
subscription.on('create', todo => {
    this.todos.add(todo);
    console.log('On create event');
});
```

Comment: Share the code please

Comment: Im using websockets and its working ok. Can you give some more details ?

Comment: Im using Parse Platform JS SDK and running on android as an Ionic app, it works on iOS in the simulator but i dont see any of the livequery websocket hooks getting triggered on android i am updating my question above with more info

Comment: Would you mind to share the code that you are using to initialize the sdk and create the subscription?